# Want to plot Pandas Dataframe as Multiple Histograms with log10 scale x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, logarithm

I have floating point data in a Pandas dataframe. Each column represents a variable (they have string names) and each row a set of values (the rows have integer names which are not important).

```
>>> print data
0      kppawr23    kppaspyd
1      3.312387   13.266040
2      2.775202    0.100000
3    100.000000  100.000000
4    100.000000   39.437420
5     17.017150   33.019040
...
```

I want to plot a histogram for each column. The best result I have achieved is with the hist method of dataframe:

```
data.hist(bins=20)
```

but I want the x-axis of each histogram to be on a log10 scale. And the bins to be on log10 scale too, but that is easy enough with bins=np.logspace(-2,2,20).

A workaround might be to log10 transform the data before plotting, but the approaches I have tried,

```
data.apply(math.log10)
```

and

```
data.apply(lambda x: math.log10(x))
```

give me a floating point error.

```
    "cannot convert the series to {0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>", u'occurred at index kppawr23')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

`data.hist()` returns an array of axes. You'll need to call
`ax.set_xscale('log')` for each axes, `ax` to make each of the logarithmically
scaled.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 100
arr = np.random.random((N,2)) * np.logspace(-2,2,N)[:, np.newaxis]
data = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['kppawr23', 'kppaspyd'])

bins = np.logspace(-2,2,20)
axs = data.hist(bins=bins)
for ax in axs.ravel():
    ax.set_xscale('log')

plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

By the way, to take the log of every value in the DataFrame, `data`, you could use

```
logdata = np.log10(data)
```

because NumPy ufuncs (such as `np.log10`) can be applied to pandas DataFrames because they operate [elementwise on all the values in the DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe-interoperability-with-numpy-functions).

`data.apply(math.log10)` did not work because `apply` tries to pass an entire column (a Series) of values to `math.log10`. `math.log10` expects a scalar value only.

`data.apply(lambda x: math.log10(x))` fails for the same reason that `data.apply(math.log10)` does. Moreover, if `data.apply(func)` and `data.apply(lambda x: func(x))` were both viable options, the first should be preferred since the lambda function would just make the call a tad slower.

You could use `data.apply(np.log10)`, again since the NumPy ufunc `np.log10` can be applied to Series, but there is no reason to bother doing this when `np.log10(data)` works.

You could also use `data.applymap(math.log10)` since `applymap` calls
`math.log10` on each value in `data` one-at-a-time. But this would be far slower
than calling the equivalent NumPy function, `np.log10` on the entire
DataFrame. Still, it is worth knowing about `applymap` in case you need to call
some custom function which is not a ufunc.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about ravel(). I haven't delved into numpy either. I have been trying to focus on pandas because it if extremely fast at reading in large data sets.

Comment: By the way, is there any way to speed it up? I have 219 histograms to produce and it takes minutes (running in debug mode in PyCharm community edition).

Comment: And can I apply tight_layout to data.hist somehow?

Comment: You could use `plt.gcf().tight_layout()`; I've edited the post above. You might be able to speed things up by using the `multiprocessing` module to divvy up the work among processors. The [Python Module of the Week tutorial on multiprocessing](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) would be a good place to begin.